# Autenticação com Spring Boot, Security, Usando Página Html, Usuário e Senha do Banco

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Olá,

Estou iniciando com o Spring Boot e estou travado em um problema com a configuração do spring security. Estou tentando fazer a parte de login da página, fiz as configurações com o que achei de material na internet mas não esta dando certo.
O problema é o seguinte, ao abrir a página padrão de login do spring security eu tento fazer login com o usuário cadastrado no banco mas ele diz que não existe, só consigo fazer login com o usuário padrão do spring, "user" e a senha gerada automaticamente: "Using generated security password: b8728e...". Como faço para desativar este usuário padrão para fazer a pesquisa por usuário no meu banco?

Tentei também utilizar usuário em memória mas tb não deu.

Classes de configuração:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityWebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ImplementsUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/" ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().permitAll()      
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));

          }

      @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("lucas").password("123").roles("ADMIN");

        //userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        //.passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

    }

    @Override  
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/imagem/**", "/js/**");
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public class ImplementsUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository ur;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nomeusuario) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Usuario usuario = ur.findByNomeusuario(nomeusuario);

        if(usuario == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario não encontrado!"); 

        return usuario;
    }

}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {

    Usuario findByNomeusuario(String nomeusuario);

}
```

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {

        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {

        return "login";
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable, UserDetails{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long idUsuario;

    private String nomeusuario;


    private String senha;


    private float salario;


    public long getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }


    public void setIdUsuario(long idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }



    public String getNomeusuario() {
        return nomeusuario;
    }


    public void setNomeUsuario(String nomeusuario) {
        this.nomeusuario = nomeusuario;
    }


    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }


    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }


    public float getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }


    public void setSalario(float salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }


    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.senha;
    }


    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.nomeusuario;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {

        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você não vai conseguir mesmo, pois, a autenticação não está buscando do banco de dados, reveja teu arquivo SecurityWebConfig no método configure, você está usando: auth.inMemoryAuthentication(), e deve utilizar: userDetailsService no qual está comentado

Comment: o método findByNomeusuario está estranho, verifique se ele realmente está funcionando e como está a nomenclatura na Entidade, não seria, findByNomeUsuario?

Comment: Esta com o auth.inMemoryAuthentication() pois estava testando, mas com o que esta comentado também não funcionou.
Sobre o findByNomeUsuario, eu fiz da mesma forma como esta no model Usuario que esta nomeusuario

Comment: troque findByNomeusuario por findByNomeUsuario

Comment: no banco de dados a senha deve estar criptografada, pois você está usando BCryptPasswordEncoder no Spring

Comment: findByNomeUsuario assim da erro. Vou alterar no banco e no model pra ver se é isso

Comment: Sim, no banco esta criptografada

Comment: poste na pergunta a tua Entidade e como está no banco

Comment: Postei na pergunta

Comment: Esse exemplo está completo, no teu falta o CustomAuthenticationManager, porém, ele utiliza JWT: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149735/autentica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-spring-security?rq=1

Comment: No meu `ImplementsUserDetailsService`, eu tenho essas configurações:        

    @Resource(name = "usuarioService")
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
        public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
        }

Comment: o teu `ImplementsUserDetailsService` está errado, você precisa anotá-lo com `@Service(value = "usuarioService")` ao invés de `@Repository`

Comment: Alterei para identificar os parametros pelos que eu criei: `.formLogin().usernameParameter("nomeUsuario").passwordParameter("senha").loginPage("/login") .permitAll()` mas não deu tb, vou tentar fazer estas outras alterações que você mandou

Comment: qual é a versão do teu spring? spring mvc 4? mvc 3? é spring boot?

Comment: Spring boot 2.1.6

Comment: atualizei minha resposta, estou usando o Spring Boot 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uma implementação de **Spring Boot** com **Security** simples só para isso, com acesso de **Usuario** e **Senha** via **Html**, banco de dados **Postgres** porém, pode ser qualquer outro sql.

Com uma tabela: `user`
Com os campos: `id`, `username`, `password`

Se quiser pode criar a tabela no **postgres** com o comando:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL
);
```

Mas também pode deixar para o hibernate gerar para você configurando o arquivo: `application.properties` com a seguinte instrução:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Se realmente desejar criar a tabela na mão, então, mude essa instrução para validate:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Implementação para UserDetailsService:

```
package hello;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service(value = "usuarioService")
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepo usuarioRepo;    

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        Optional<User> opt = usuarioRepo.findByUsername(username);
        User user = null;
        if(opt.isPresent()){
            user = opt.get();
        }
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
    }

    public User save(User usuario) {
        usuario.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(usuario.getPassword()));
        return usuarioRepo.save(usuario);
    }
}
```

Implementação de UserDetails:

```
package hello;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8489053074208206273L;

    private User user;

    public MyUserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Entidade User:

```
package hello;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {

    //FIXME: #### está funcionando, mas o ideal é depois avaliar o uso de Sequence, Identity, Serial...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;


}
```

Repositorio:

```
package hello;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepo extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Implementação de WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
package hello;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //FIXME: #### após os testes, remover o mapeamento new-user tanto da controller como das permissoes abaixo ####
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/new-user").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Resource(name = "usuarioService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

}
```

Controller:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

    //FIXME: #### quando tudo já estiver ok, e o usuário já criado, remover o mapeamento new-user ####

@Controller
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailService usuarioService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new-user")
    public String newUser() {
        User usuario = new User();
        usuario.setId(1L);
        usuario.setUsername("danilo");
        usuario.setPassword("123");
        usuarioService.save(usuario);
        return usuario.toString();
    }

}
```

`Pom.xml` usando **postgres**, **jpa**, **thymeleaf**, e **lombok**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-securing-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**:

Configure o banco de dados, usuário e senha

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=100000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=50
#escolha um banco de dados, nesse caso esta: dbteste 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbteste
spring.datasource.username=userteste
spring.datasource.password=senha
#create ira criar a tabela
#create-drop ao encerrar a aplicacao ele dropa as tabelas
#validate ele verifica se as tabelas estao conforme as entidades
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create #validate #create-drop
```

hello.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

foram criadas as páginas (**home.html**,**hello.html**,**login.html**)  utilizando a convenção do thymeleaf+spring boot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Execute o comando:

**No linux**:
    mvn clean install; java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -jar target/gs-securing-web-0.1.0.jar

**No Windows:**
    mvn clean install & java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -jar target/gs-securing-web-0.1.0.jar

Entre na página:

```
http://localhost:8080/new-user
```

Vai aparecer uma página de erro, pois, ele vai tentar enviar para um template do thymeleaf que não existe, porém, com o usuário criado na descrição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entre agora na página:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

Você não vai estar logado e vai ser redirecionado, entre com o login, e senha: danilo, 123

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após logar, você será automaticamente redirecionado para a página hello:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz estas alterações mas não deu em nada. Ta difícil kkkk. 
Eu acredito que o que ta gerando este problema seja a questão de o spring security estar  gerando uma senha para logar

Comment: adicionei o método save, utilize-o para criar um usuário.

Comment: Achei uma apostila da Caelum aqui, vou tentar fazer do zero esta parte e ver no que vai dar. Se der certo posto aqui. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção :)

Comment: fiz uma implementação com uso de página utilizando usuario+senha só para isso e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @LucasCarravetta, e coloquei na resposta, com toda a estrutura.